# Django hidden field input, custom widget w/media rendering issues

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a Django widget; it is a hidden input text field that has a JavaScript media file associated with it. This JavaScript media creates an ajax file uploader and requires 1 parameter; the id of the element it should append to. Upon a successful upload, the JavaScript uploader returns the location of the file as a string, and sets the value of the hidden field with it.

This stops working when I simply hard-code the id of the element the JS created-widget should append to as the parent of the hidden field; the widget doesn't even show up. I am thinking this has something to do with the input being hidden. Anyways, any general direction would be appreciated in this. If additional context is needed, let me know.

Comment: It would help if you showed the relevant lines of code, and show what you have tried. (one line of code is worth 1000 words)

Comment: you are right @Lycha. Unfortunately, it is spread over several files and I feel like too much context is required. I will close this question.